# Migrating from beta to release repository

Tags: ubuntu, php, aptitude, ubuntu-16.04

Okay, so I'm probably having a hard time finding an answer for this as I don't know if I'm using the correct terminology for it.

In short, I installed php7.0 a while ago before it was available in the main package repositories for Ubuntu, as such I installed it via adding the address of a beta repository and installing it from there.

However, there are now proper release versions available, so I'd like to remove the beta repository and switch to the release versions from now on. How do I this?

Also, I already appear to have accidentally upgraded to the latest beta release, so I believe this means I will need to downgrade some packages.

At the moment it looks like the version I want is `7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3`, but what I have installed is `7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`. I use `aptitude` for installations if that makes any difference.

Comment: Where were you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How can PPAs be removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) to remove the beta repo and then just run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade php7.0
```